# how i can make a clear button in jquery date picker work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to use jQuery datepicker by popup window to select date and fill in text field in diffrent window.(datepicker and textfield they are in diffrent window)

I directly add some code for clear button in jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
in DIV of buttonpanel in datepicker

```
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_'+
B+".datepicker._clearDate(this);\">Clear</button>
```

and my popup window code like this.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
                            {
                                var doc = window.opener.form;
                                doc.textfieldname.value = dateText;
                                window.close();
                            }
                    });
            });


<div id="datepicker" align="center"></div>
```

How can I make clear button work by clear all text in textfield

Answer (score 1):

I alreadty found the solution by aad id to clear button like

```
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_'+
B+".datepicker._clearDate(this);\" id = "BTClear" >Clear</button>
```

and you can use clear by id like html button